# How can I get a number between two words with REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Tags: regex, oracle, substring

I would like to retrieve a sequence of numbers in between two strings. The text may have other numbers and I only want to get the sequence in between 'item ' and ' n' (first occurrence). Also, the length of the sequence can vary.

The following is what I have tried:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(clob_text, 'item ([0-9]+?) n') AS my_number FROM my_table WHERE something = something;
```

However it returns the value "item 123456789 n", and I want only the number value.

I have also tried the regex '\item ([0-9]+?) \n' which returns the same, and '(?=item )([0-9]+?)(?= n)' and '\item /([0-9]+?)/ \n', that returns nothing.

At last, I tried to intercalate the expressions and it worked but is not ideal:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(clob_text, '\item ([0-9]+?) \n'), '[0-9]+') FROM ...
```

How can I remove these unwanted characters so the result would be only "123456789" with one expression only?

Example input:
'Somdasdas dasd sdaisdjas asod dasdhjs 1564, dasdohndsdias sdasdasdasdasds,
ddissd ksdnas skid as 5645 sdnaslndas,  ndsadn ndasknd dnsd: sdas 5465 asdasd
dnaskldnas ojsd (dasdksdas) asdklhasdas dsd. isdjasdsdpoojs asdasdasdasdsad
46564 iasdonsoi sdjosd kjlsdk kkpnasd item 12345879 não-existente da lista 14
sdasdnsd jdspka 2564 sadasds.'

Expected output:
'12345879'

Comment: The example you've shown doesn't cover the range of possibilities that could be present in your data. For eg, what should be returned if there are 2 numbers or when there are **only** numbers. The answer will depend on that. So,add more examples and specify the expected result for each, preferably in a tabular format.

Comment: Hi. You are right. I just edit the post with more details. Thanks!

Comment: The edit isn't helping. As I stated clearly, the data samples and expected output is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the regular expression for your problem:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('<your string>', '\item ([0-9]*?) \n', 1, 1, null, 1)
```

**Usage:**

- *?     Matches the preceding pattern zero or more occurrences.
- ( )    Used to group expressions as a subexpression.
- [0-9]  Matches any digit.

Query with actual data and output:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('Somdasdas dasd sdaisdjas asod dasdhjs 1564, dasdohndsdias sdasdasdasdasds, ddissd ksdnas skid as 5645 sdnaslndas, ndsadn ndasknd dnsd: sdas 5465 asdasd dnaskldnas ojsd (dasdksdas) asdklhasdas dsd. isdjasdsdpoojs asdasdasdasdsad 46564 iasdonsoi sdjosd kjlsdk kkpnasd item 12345879 não-existente da lista 14 sdasdnsd jdspka 2564 sadasds'
    , '\item ([0-9]*?) \n', 1, 1, null, 1) as MY_STRING
FROM
    DUAL;


Output:

MY_STRIN
--------
12345879
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07521dab6ab887f3289d7038a3e69d32)

Cheers!!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are always looking for a single number embedded between 2 strings

```
 regexp_substr('item 123456789 n','[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+',1,1,null,1)
                               --^anything    ^1 or more  first match^
                               -- other than a       digits
                               -- digit occurring 
                               -- one or more times.
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=211c69df112517dc707c48912d1de6f2)

Comment: regexp_substr('abc 123 item 123456789 n','[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+',1,1,null,1)` --> `123`. It is not giving `123456789`

Comment: @Tejash : I've edited my answer mentioning it's scope. It's up to the OP whether or not to accept it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. The regex does not work because I have other numbers in the text. But you guys gave me an idea to solve it by using intercalated regex. It is not ideal but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @DamaresOliveria : you will get better solutions in SO if questions you ask contain sufficient information of the scope of the problem

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with regular expressions, I have a tendency to try and make things way too complicated. In this case, the simple solution is

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('item 123456789 n', '[0-9]+')
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ae3528770ae5a51838e2f3dd3566908c)

Comment: This will become true even when only a number is present

Comment: OP didn't say that was a problem. Only that you need to pull the numbers out from the middle of the string.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response. But this is not quite what I need because I may have other numbers in the text and I only want the one in between 'item ' and ' n'. However you gave me an idea to solve it. SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(clob_text, '\item ([0-9]+?) \n'), '[0-9]+') FROM ...